# how to divide the float number into 2 or 3 pieces

Tags: c

So I just received my paper. its said if the input number is `0.001001001` (repeated) it's gonna print `0.001...`, if it's `0.015015015`, then `0.015...` as a print, if the number is `998` its should be `0.998...` my idea is to divide it into something like 2 pieces but im still cant figure its out. thanks

```
scanf("%f",&num1);
scanf("%f",&num2);
scanf("%f",&num3);

num1 = floor(1000*(num1/999))/1000;
num2 = floor(1000*(num2/999))/1000;
num3 = floor(1000*(num3/999))/1000;

printf("%.3f...\n",num1);
printf("%.3f...\n",num2);
printf("%.3f...\n",num3);
```

input = 3 integers that divide to 999, the value is below 999

output = the result, if the result repeated (0.001001001) then its going to print out 0.001...

sample :

input = output

3 = 0.003...

10 = 0.010...

998 = 0.998...

**Note:** I tried it with the floor so i guess there's something error about my logic

Comment: "if the number is 998 its should be 0.998" are you sure, this don't make sense, do you mean "0.998e4" ?

Comment: I don't think using *numeric* types is a good idea here. Use strings.

Comment: What is the input to your program? It looks like it is expecting three floating point numbers (in text form) separated by whitespace.

Comment: @Stargateur yes the sample is like that :)

Comment: can i /999 with the strings ?@EugeneSh.

Comment: @rarblack Why did you add irrelevant tags?

Comment: @IanAbbott the input is 3 integers and i need to divide it to 999

Comment: You should show the specification from the project you were assigned more clearly. Learning precision in stating what the problem to be solved is is an important skill. The rephrasing presented in this question is unclear and sloppy, to the point where we cannot understand it.

Comment: sorry im kinda bad with that, but i just modified it

Answer (score 0):

Since the value is *below* 999, 999 *not* included, just read the integer, and print it with `0.%03d...`:

```
int num;

scanf("%d", &num);
printf("0.%03d...\n", num);
```

The conversion specification `%03d` will print the given integer in base-10, with *leading zeroes prepended* so that it is at least 3 characters wide. For 3, it will print `003`, for `10` it will print `010` and for `976` it will print `976`.

What you specifically *cannot do this with* are *floats*. Floats in your computer are *binary numbers* and they cannot precisely produce decimal fractions... nor can they do infinite precision.

Comment: hellooo its really helpfull but, its still 50 of 100. my teacher said some case need to print in a long version without "..."

Answer (score 0):

If`x` is near some 0.abcabcabc... pattern, scale is by *999 and then /1000.

```
   abc.abcabc...     1000x
-    0.abcabcabc...     1x
-------------------
   abc.               999 x
/ 1000
-------------------
     0.abc
```

Mathematically this works to exact 3 digits.  Yet we are working with `double`.

`double` is usual encoded as [binary64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format) and can  not exactly represent, 0.001..., 0.015..., 0.998... and so the above idea will result in values very near the intended.  The `* 999` and `/ 1000` steps may impart a small departure from the mathematical result too.

```
int cajunb_print(double x) {
  printf("(before %.*e) ", DBL_DECIMAL_DIG, x);
  x = x * (1000 - 1) / 1000;
  printf("(after %.*e) ", DBL_DECIMAL_DIG, x);
  return printf("%.3f...\n", x);
}

int main(void) {
  cajunb_print(0.001001001001001001);
  cajunb_print(0.015015015015015015);
  cajunb_print(0.998998998998998998);
  return 0;
}
```

Output

```
(before 1.00100100100100099e-03) (after 1.00000000000000002e-03) 0.001...
(before 1.50150150150150149e-02) (after 1.49999999999999994e-02) 0.015...
(before 9.98998998998999022e-01) (after 9.97999999999999998e-01) 0.998...
```