# How to disable the rounded off on C programming

Tags: c

I want to get `998 / 999 = 0.998`, but I get `0.999`.

Can you help me?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
int main() {
    float a,b,c;
    float d,e,f;

    scanf("%f", &a);
    d= a / 999;
    scanf("%f", &b);
    e= b / 999;
    scanf("%f", &c);
    f= c / 999;

    printf("%.3f...\n", d);
    printf("%.3f...\n", e);
    printf("%.3f...\n", f);
}
```

Comment: The question is, what should be help you with? `998 / 999 =0.99899899` which is equal to (rounded to 3 decimals) `0.999`. So there is nothing wrong with your code.

Comment: Do not apply to format in printf(). If you used formatter then remaining digit round off and you didn't get your expected digits. use %f instead of %.3f.

Comment: Out of curiosity: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/q/52784022/2410359

Answer (score 4):

Notwithstanding the fact that `998 / 999` is `0.998999...9`, if you want to *truncate* on the 3rd significant figure, then one way is to write, from C99 onwards

```
truncf(998.f / 999 * 1000) / 1000;
```

or

```
floorf(998.f / 999 * 1000) / 1000;
```

You might find that the second way is more likely to be available pre-C99, if not then use say `(long)` in place of `floorf`, and replace the final division with `1000.f`.

These can introduce joke digits from about the 7th significant figure, but the formatting choice you already use will obviate that.

Answer (score 4):

The result is 0.99899899... so rounding it to 3 decimals should yield 0.999 and your program does that correctly.

If your intention is to round **down** with 3 decimals, then you must tell the program to do that instead. For that, you can use the `floor` function included in the math library you're using:

```
floor(998.0/999.0*1000)/1000;
```

Comment: More likely OP wants to `trunc()` than `floor()`  (same for positive values)